# Load a series of 3D models using OpenGL (Streaming 3D model?)

Tags: c++, opengl

My application produces a stream of 3D models, say in .obj format. Each model is a 3D mesh with texture. I wonder how I can display/visualize a stream of 3D models using OpenGL. My thought is just to load the 3D models sequentially, but I am not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need code for loading a 3D model from obj file.
   Either write it yourself, or find an implementation online. Search for e.g. "obj model parsing c++".

   For some more info about the obj format see here:
   [Wikipedia - Wavefront .obj file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file).
2. Each model should probably be loaded into an instance of a class like this:

```
class Model
{
public:
    bool LoadObj(std::string const & filename);
     
    using VertexPosition = std::array<float, 3>;
    std::vector<VertexPosition> const &  GetVerticesPositions();
     
    using VertexColor = std::array<unsigned char, 4>;
    std::vector<VertexColor> const & GetVerticesColors();
    
    using FaceIndices = std::array<int, 3>;
    std::vector<FaceIndices> const & GetFacesIndices();
    
    using VertexUV = std::array<float, 2>;
    std::vector<VertexUV> const & GetVerticesUVs();
     
    int GetTextureWidth();
    int GetTextureHeight();
    unsigned char const * GetTextureData();
     
    // etc...
};
```

3. All the models can be stored in a `std::vector<Model>`.
4. Your application should have a timer for rendering.
   Each time you need to render a frame you need to determine which model to render,
   based on the time passed and frames-per-second.
   When you pick a model, you can render it using the interface of `Model`.
5. If you have many models and do not want to require too much memory, you can do a delay load (load from file only when yo need it).
   This technique requires to load some frames in advance, on a separate thread (i.e. buffering).
   Otherwise your playing will not be smooth as you will need to wait to load the obj file which can take some time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Currently, I can load a 3D model in .obj format and draw + render the 3D model with OpenGL.  I can also load the next 3D model in obj, but I am stuck on drawing the new model.I guess I will need to clean the window and draw the new model. But not so sure how to do so. BTW, each 3D model is loaded in a VOB.

Comment: Every time you render a new model for the next frame, you need to transfer all the buffers (indices, vertex positions etc.) to opengl. This is done using APIs like `glBindBuffer`, `glBufferData` etc. If you succeeded to render the first model you should be familiar with them.

Comment: Yes, glBindBuffer and glBufferData are the functions that I used for creating VOB. Currently, I can load and render the current and the next 3D model separately. But I get stuck trying to show them one by one.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly goes wrong. You said you managed to push the data to opengl and render the first frame. What do you see if you push the next frame data and try to render the same way ?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. For simplicity, I assume to have all 3D models available, so I just load data for all frames beforehand and try to show them sequentially like doing an animation. After I draw the first frame, I try to erase the first frame and draw the next frame... . The issue is that all models show up at once.

Comment: You can try to load data to opengl frame by frame. Each time you load one frame you should render it and verify you see what you expect. If this works you can try to resolve the issue of loading multiple frames.

Comment: @Gavin you are... not clear how to clean the window and draw the new model? Why don't you just call glClear to clear the window, and then draw the new model?